# How to randomize and turn a string into a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I'm building a game of Hangman as my first python project. The game is currently being run in the terminal as I build it. I'm not using PyGame. Here's more of the relevant code.

```
five_letters = ['birds', 'hands', 'trees']
difficulty = 'easy'

def get_word(foo):
"""Based on difficulty generate a game_word, then turn it into a list to be returned"""
    if foo == 'easy':
        foo = random.choice(five_letters)
        foo = list(foo)

    if foo == 'medium':
        foo = random.choice(ten_letters)
        foo = list(foo)

    if foo == 'hard':
        foo = random.choice(fifteen_letters)
        foo = list(foo)

    return foo

game_word = get_word(difficulty)
```

I want to take the list and do the following:

- Check if the player's guess is in the list ( I know I can iterate over a string).
- If the guess is in the string place it in the appropriate space in the output.

I'm returning the string as a list so that I can find the value of a correct guess within the list to place it in the correct spot in the output.

For instance

```
game_word = 'birds'
player_guess = 's'
```

I want to output

```
_ _ _ _ s
```

But maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I just felt like I could shorten the part of the function that selected a random string and then turned it into a list.

Comment: `foo = list(random.choice(a_list))`?

Comment: `random.sample(a_list, 1)` would be my choice (it returns a list regardless of the sample size).

Comment: Show the intended output.

Comment: What exactly do you want to output here? Choose a random element from a list and return it in a list of size 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
from random import choice
foo = [choice(a_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that I see it the syntax looks obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also starting my journey with Python 3.x and here is my quick code which I just made (you can use it for reference if you get stuck or something):

```
from random import choice as chc

def hangman(diff):
    #Fill in the words for every difficulty type:
    easy = ['this', 'that']
    medium = ['bicycle', 'bathroom']
    hard = ['superlongword', 'othersuperlongw']
    if diff == 'easy':
        word = chc(easy)
    elif diff == 'medium':
        word = chc(medium)
    elif diff == 'hard':
        word = chc(hard)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Bad difficulty choosen. Terminating.')
    shadow = ['_' for item in word] #list which is showing the progress
    shad_str = ''
    for item in shadow:
        shad_str += item
    print('Choosen word is {} characters long and looks like this:\n{}'.format(len(shad_str), shad_str))
    while '_' in shadow:
        letter = input('Type in next char: ')
        if len(letter) == 1:    #anti-cheat - always have to give 1 char
            if letter in word:
                for i in range(len(word)):   #makes it work correctly even when the letter shows up more than one time
                    if(letter == word[i]):
                        shadow[i] = letter
                temp = ''
                for item in shadow:
                    temp += item
                print(temp)
            else:
                print("This letter isn't in the choosen word! Try again.")
        else:
                print('No cheating! Only one character allowed!')
    else:
        shad_str = ''
        for item in shadow:
            shad_str += item
        print('The game has ended. The word was "{}".'.format(shad_str))
```

I'm sure the whole thing with the checking can be done in a function (that's why this is a case just for 'easy' mode) so you can call the 'play' function 3 times depending on which difficulty mode you choose.
EDIT: That was not needed, I just noticed you can just decide of the diff with 3 ifs. Now the game works every time if user picks right difficulty.

Comment: thanks for this. You're trick to iterate over the word has been helpful while I'm working on my version today.